# JSOUP connect UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, jsoup

I try to access a webpage with JSOUP but I have problems with UTF-8 Characters. 
This works fine for ULRs without special characters.

```
    String linkTeam = "https://www.fifaindex.com/de/team/" + team.getId() + "/" + URLEncoder.encode(team.getName().replaceAll(" ", ""),"UTF-8");
    System.out.println(linkTeam);
    String name = URLEncoder.encode(team.getName().replaceAll(" ", ""), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(name);
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(linkTeam).get();
    Elements strength = doc.getElementsByClass("badge r3");
    team.setSturm(Integer.parseInt(strength.get(0).text()));
    team.setMittelfeld(Integer.parseInt(strength.get(1).text()));
    team.setAbwehr(Integer.parseInt(strength.get(2).text()));
    return team;
```

This is the Output for URLs with UTF-8 characters:

```
https://www.fifaindex.com/de/team/1877/BocaJuniors
BocaJuniors
https://www.fifaindex.com/de/team/110395/Lan%C3%BAs
Lan%C3%BAs
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error 
fetching URL. Status=404, 
URL=https://www.fifaindex.com/de/team/110395/Lan%25C3%25BAs
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:679)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:628)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:249)
at fifa.scraper.Scraper.getTeamStrength(Scraper.java:71)
at fifa.scraper.Scraper.loadTeams(Scraper.java:60)
at fifa.scraper.Scraper.main(Scraper.java:23)
```

When I use Jsoup.connect there is "25" added to the URL. When I print the URL by System.out.println() the URL works. Without URLEncoder in the first line the output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=https://www.fifaindex.com/de/team/110395/Lan%2525C3%2525BAs/
```

So how can i connect to an URL with UTF-8 characters? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that in you case server respond with 301 status and location header already contains encoded url, but Jsoup encode it one more time. The code snippet below works for me

```
private static Document sendRequest(String url) {
        Document doc = null;
        try {
            Connection connect = Jsoup.connect(url);
            connect.request().followRedirects(false);
            URI u = new URI(url);
            doc = connect.url(new URI(u.getScheme(), u.getUserInfo(), u.getHost(), u.getPort(), URLDecoder.decode(u.getPath(), "UTF-8"), u.getQuery(), u.getFragment()).toURL()).get();
            if (connect.response().statusCode() == 301 && connect.response().header("Location") != null) {
                return sendRequest(connect.response().header("Location"));
            }
            return doc;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return doc;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String url = null;
        url = "https://www.fifaindex.com/de/team/110395/Lanús";
//        url = "https://www.fifaindex.com/de/team/1877/BocaJuniors";
        Document doc = sendRequest(url);
        Elements strength = doc.getElementsByClass("badge r3");
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(strength.get(0).text()));
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(strength.get(1).text()));
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(strength.get(2).text()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but when i remove UrlEncoder.encode the Exception is: Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404, URL=https://www.fifaindex.com/de/team/110395/Lan%2525C3%2525BAs/  so there is two times extra "25"

Comment: Looks like I found problem. Server sometimes returns 301 code and location for redirect. and this location already encoded, but JSOUP encode it one more time. Will prepare code snippet.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. I searched for it the whole day. Thank You